# Favicon in SharePoint Hosted Custom App

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

How do you set the favicon of a SharePoint hosted custom app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In hosted app, favicon is being set from the master page. In `Default.aspx` page, you will find the name of the master page.

```
<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Language="C#" %>
```

So open your master page and set favicon.

As per discussion over chat, you need to change it from client side. Following should work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.type = 'image/x-icon';
    link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
    link.href = 'yourUrl/favicon.ico';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
});
```

Comment: I've heard that it's not recommended to change the Master Page due to the "Tax Of Customization", where future updates will not be pushed by Microsoft. So if I change the Master Page, will this happen?

Comment: Can you give me that reference? as far as I know changing in the **html** master page will not hamper future update.

Comment: I've heard it from a MVP in SharePoint, don't have documentation supporting his claims, but not sure if he was referring to this Master Pages or some other.

Comment: btw, how do you open the master page. New to SP dev :) https://domain-05a10625cb8cc8.sharepoint.com/sites/isurudev/masterurl/default.master responds with 404 NOT FOUND

Comment: How your MVP has recommended you to add script in master page? You just have to change the link of the  favicon. for this nothing gonna break in future update I guess.

Comment: From designer open the site where you have deployed the app. then find your default master page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31708/discussion-between-isuru-and-atish-dipongkor).